# AR face filters with live stream using wowza engine

Tags: android

So far I have successfully able to create stream and view it using wowza but the problem is integrating Ar face masks into the live stream and I have tried using DeepAR SDK but it supports only webRTC but rtmp stream is not supported with DeepAR and neither wowza has face filters in its SDK.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know DeepAR - but I do know that Wowza Streaming Engine does support WebRTC both as input and output; see https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-webrtc-with-wowza-streaming-engine

Typically if you want to do any image-processing with Wowza, you must use transcoding and hook into the process at the moment where the incoming video frame has been decoded and before it's being re-encoded. That will give you the raw frame data in a byte array which you then can run through a image processing engine. But it takes lots of resources (CPU not at least), especially with a Live stream where the image processing must happen at the fps speed. Wowza wasn't really built for this, IMO.